# Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]

Tags: java, string, syntax, integer

Since I want the user to enter numbers instead of Strings I used

```
public static void main(Integer[] args)
```

So, why is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main is special since it has to be present to start the program, so it's required to have a fixed signature.  Under the hood, the java runtime looks for the magic signature to start the program.  The magic signature is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If you want to get Integers, you'll need to parse them out after the fact, using

```
Integer.parseInt( x );
```

Comment: That should be `Integer.parseInt(..)`.

Answer (score 4):

The signature on your main method MUST be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

You don't have any other option. You may parse those strings as integers if you need to, via `Integer.parseInt(someString)`

Answer (score 2):

You can **only** have an array of String[] for your main method (unless you overload it, but let's not get into the details for now :-D).

However, you can change each element of the String[] args into an int by using [Integer.parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), something like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int[] values = new int[args.length];
 for (String arg : args)
 {
  //Get or do something with the integer value here
 }
}
```

This is because the underlying platform only knows how to pass **Strings** to your program. When you open up a command prompt or terminal and do:

`>java MyClass 3 4 5`

It doesn't know that you want ["3","4","5"] treated like integers. It leaves dealing with the Strings up to the program.

Answer (score 1):

When the JVM loads your class and tries to execute it, it looks for the method main() with the signature

```
public static void main (String[] args) ...
```

Anything else is unaccptable. If you are expecting integers, use the Integer.parseInt() method to convert the input Strings to integers, as Zach mentioned. I'd put that conversion in a try-catch block to catch NumberFormatException, and have a

```
System.err.println ("This class accepts Integer arguments only");
```

in the corresponding catch block. Regards, - M.S.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to accept a string array, and convert the strings to integers at runtime. Just the way it works...

Answer (score 0):

the method signature for main is always (String[] args). If you are going to get Integers, then you have to convert the args[] to int using the snippet below

```
  int aInt = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```